# Data-bind for style not working in knockout js

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

[myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHALs/)

style binding not works in knockout js. I dont know why its not working?

code :

```
<div class="sample" data-bind="style:{color:'blue'}">
    hai
</div>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `ko.applyBindings()`.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fHALs/2/)

Comment: I don't understand your question Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Is apply bindings needed for non observable items too?

Comment: Yes, you need to call ko.applyBindings to start Knockout. `ko.applyBindings({})` bound the `{}` to the body element and process them `data-bind` attributes